# Javascript execute function from click

Tags: javascript, html, dry

I have these three function that I would like to apply the DRY principles too.

JS

```
function shakeBell(){
  document.getElementById('shakeBell').play();
}

function shakeShake() {
  document.getElementById('shakeShake').play();
}

function blowWhistle(){
  document.getElementById('blowWhistle').play();
}
```

HTML

```
<audio id="shakeBell"  src="audio/bell-ringing-02.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
<audio id="shakeShake"  src="audio/pill-bottle-1.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
<audio id="blowWhistle"  src="whistle-flute-2.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>

<div class="imagelist">
<a href="javascript:shakeBell();">
<img src="images/Golden_Bell.png" style="width:100px; height 100px;"></a>
<img src="images/Maracas.png" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
</div>
```

I have multiple images that when clicked plays the specific sound file for that picture. How can i do this without making separate functions for each image?

Comment: why not passing the element's id as an argument to your function?

Answer (score 3):

You can do a single function with one parameter, like:

```
function shake(id){
  document.getElementById(id).play();
}
```

Then you could call it:

```
<a href="javascript:shake('shakeBell');">
<img src="images/Golden_Bell.png" style="width:100px; height 100px;"></a>
```

Comment: An event listener is a better way to go than inline JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
  function playSound(data) {
        document.getElementById(data).play();
}
```

HTML:

```
<audio id="shakeBell"  src="audio/bell-ringing-02.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
<audio id="shakeShake"  src="audio/pill-bottle-1.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
<audio id="blowWhistle"  src="whistle-flute-2.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>

<div class="imagelist">
    <img src="images/Golden_Bell.png" style="width:100px; height 100px;" onClick="playSound("shakeBell)">
    <img src="images/Maracas.png" style="width:100px; height:100px;" onClick="playSound("shakeBell)">
</div>
```

Comment: If if if? Data can only be one of the three. An if else if Else statement or a switch would be better. Igor's answer is more scalable since regardless of what `data` is you call the same function `document.getElementById (data).play ()`

Comment: @MatthewCiaramitaro you're wrong. these are back to back if statements.you're right that the other structures are more correct.

Comment: @MatthewCiaramitaro I editet it, but your are right, there are to many if-statements, the answer from Igor is the best...

Comment: @catbadger Back to back if statements have 3 comparisons. if else has best case 1 comparison worst case 3. A switch table has one lookup. And using data as the id in the first place avoids all of that. I dont see where I am wrong

Comment: @LarsS. Your edit made the 3 if statements extraneous. They all do the same thing so long as data is one of the three. You could write it as one if statement with `||`s

Comment: @LarsS. Right. Although you could use 1 to prevent user errors though (or do the handling somewhere else) ie if the function calls data is called with an id that does not match an audio file, then an error will be logged.

Answer (score -1):

Define an event listener rather than inline JS. Give the anchor an ID related to the sound it plays -- in my example, I add `_a` to the ID.

```
const soundIds = ['shakeBell', 'shakeShake', 'blowWhistel'];
soundIds.forEach(function(id) {
    document.getElementById(id + '_a').addEventListener(function() {
        document.getElementById(id).play();
    });
});

<audio id="shakeBell"  src="audio/bell-ringing-02.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
<audio id="shakeShake"  src="audio/pill-bottle-1.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
<audio id="blowWhistle"  src="whistle-flute-2.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>

<div class="imagelist">
<a href="#" id="shakeBell_a">
<img src="images/Golden_Bell.png" style="width:100px; height 100px;"></a>
<img src="images/Maracas.png" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
</div>
```